# On iOS, why UIBezierPath drawing doesn't require a context?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, core-graphics

On iOS, we can draw a line in `drawRect` using

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextBeginPath (context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 100);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

but we can also draw a rectangle if we remove the above code, and just use:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[path stroke];
```

Two related questions:

1) Why doesn't `UIBezierPath` need to get or use the current context?

2) What if I have two context: one for screen, and one is a bitmap context, then how to tell which context to draw to for `UIBezierPath`?  I thought it might be `UIGraphicsSetCurrentContext` but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`UIBezierPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/) does use a context. It uses the current UIKit graphics context. This is exactly the same thing that you're already getting with [`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext).

If you want `UIBezierPath` to use a different context you can use [`UIGraphicsPushContext()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsPushContext), but you have to remember to use [`UIGraphicsPopContext()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsPopContext) when you're done.

Comment: so we would use `UIGraphicsPushContext(myBitmapContext);` to start drawing in a bitmap context?

Answer (score 7):

I thought it might be useful to mention that CGContextFillRect is ~8.5x faster than using a UIBezierPath from what I can tell (in case performance is a factor and assuming you don't need to use a UIBezierPath for more complex drawing).

I added some timing to Apple's HazardMap example (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/HazardMap/Introduction/Intro.html) and the time in ms per rect is ~0.00064 ms/rect for the CGContextFillRect approach versus ~0.00543 ms/rect for the UIBezierPath approach, presumably b/c the latter requires more message passing overhead.

i.e. I'm comparing using

```
CGContextFillRect(ctx, boundaryCGRect);
```

versus using

```
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:boundaryCGRect];
[path fill];
```

in the inner loop in HazardMapView (plus the above-mentioned changes to push / pop the context that is passed to HazardMapView drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:).

ETA

Comment: Note that the above numbers are from the iPhone 6.0 simulator running on a Macbook Pro (early 2012). Running this on an actual iPad3 CGContextFillRect seems to be ~5.7x faster than using the UIBezierPath approach. YMMV of course depending on what device you are using (the optimization settings don't seem to affect this too much).

Answer (score 5):

> On iOS, we can draw a line **in `drawRect`** using

I've highlighted the important part of this statement. Inside of `drawRect:`, a context has already been set up for you by UIKit, and any object-based drawing instructions go directly into that context. `UIBezierPath` is indeed using that context, it just doesn't need to be passed in explicitly.

In Cocoa Touch, there must always be a drawing context (in this case, the context will eventually be painted onto the screen). If you were not inside `drawRect:`, you'd have to create a context yourself.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextBeginPath (context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
```

Notice that the first function call is **Get**`CurrentContext()`. When you're using CoreGraphics' functional drawing interface, you need to pass a context into each function, but you're not creating one here, you're just retrieving the one that already exists.

[Graphics contexts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW5) are in a stack. If you want to draw into a context you've created, you push it onto the stack using `UIGraphicsPushContext()` (as Kevin already mentioned), then pop back to the previous one.